# When is my California LLC's Annual Tax due for 2016?

Tags: taxes, limited-liability-company

California form 3522 states that "the annual LLC tax is due and payable by the 15th day of the 4th month after the beginning of the LLC's taxable year (fiscal year) or April 15, 2016 (calendar year)."

Does mean my LLC's 2016 annual tax should have been paid by April 15th of this year or is it due by April 15th of 2017?

Answer (score 1):

2016 annual tax is due by April 15th 2016. Unless you know exactly why your fiscal year is not a calendar year, it is safe to assume that your LLC is using calendar year. The calendar year for 2016 starts on January 1st, so the 15th day of the 4th month after that beginning would be April 15th, 2016.